# how can i use .env file from my root directory?

Tags: environment-variables

I am working in a MERN project. I've a `.env` file in my root directory. I want to use some keys from that file on react app. can I use that `.env` file or should I make a new `.env` file?

Comment: how are you building your react application?

Comment: Using `npx create react app`

Comment: you can copy the root .env temporarily into your app folder during build / dev https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4283#issuecomment-380232039

Answer (score 1):

here is the library "dotenv" that makes it,
also have wrap for webpack "dotenv-webpack"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv